# Tax Amendment 2014

Tags: united-states, taxes, amended-tax-return

I am on H1b Visa and my husband is with me in US under F1 visa (Got SSN) from December 25,2015. I filed for tax returns with option "Married filing jointly" this year . But last year my husband was in H4 visa from November 29,2014 to January 5,2015 and I did not claim him in the tax returns. I would like to know if I can file for tax amendment and be eligible for tax returns for the previous year

Comment: Did you file as MFS or as Single in 2013?

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to file an amended return up to 3 years after the original return due date. Right now, a 2013 tax year return, due in April of 2014 can still be amended. You are asking about a return after that, so you should be fine.